# Can i use DownloadManager class in api level lower than 9?

Tags: android, download-manager

I want to download file from internet in my Android application.
I have used DownloadManager class and it works correctly on Gingerbread and above, but not on Froyo and below.

How can i use DownloadManager in api levels lower than 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i use DownloadManager in api levels lower than 9?

You can't. You will need to download the file yourself, using `HttpUrlConnection` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try HttpUrlConnection.